# C# NamedPipeServer Broken after new write

Tags: c#, named-pipes

Hello i have an arror on my NamedPipeServer.

The server and client work fine if i use a single stream WriteLine
and flush.

after i try to write new line, i have error IOException Pipe Broken.

Server Pipe

```
  NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 4);
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
                    string test;
                    sw.WriteLine("Waiting");
                    sw.Flush();
                    pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
                    test = sr.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(test);

                    if (test.Contains("Mouse"))
                    {
                        Invoke((Action)delegate
                            {
                                listBox1.Items.Add(test);
                                listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
                            });
                    }

                    if (test.Contains("Bt1"))
                    {
                        Invoke((Action)delegate
                        {
                            listBox2.Items.Add("BT");
                        });
                    }

                }

                catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }

                finally
                {
                    pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
                    if (pipeServer.IsConnected) { pipeServer.Disconnect(); }
                }
            } while (true);
```

Client Pipe

```
        NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".",
"testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None);
        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {


            if (pipeClient.IsConnected != true) { pipeClient.Connect(); }

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);

            string temp;
            temp = sr.ReadLine();

            if (temp == "Waiting")
            {
                try
                {

                    //First Write Working!
                    sw.WriteLine("Mouse Pos: " + e.Location);
                    sw.Flush();

                    //Second Write i get Exception and Pipe Broken
                    sw.WriteLine("Bt1:1");
                    sw.Flush();

                    pipeClient.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
            }
        }
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server *closes* the connection after the first line was received. So when sending the second line, the pipe is already closed (or "broken").

You should create an inner loop on your server side and add some command to close the conn

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 4);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);

do
{
    try
    {
        pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
        string test;
        sw.WriteLine("Waiting");
        sw.Flush();
        pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();

        // start inner loop
        while(pipeServer.IsConnected)
        {
            test = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(test);

            if (test.Contains("Mouse"))
            {
                Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(test);
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
                });
             }

             if (test.Contains("Bt1"))
             {
                 Invoke((Action)delegate
                 {
                     listBox2.Items.Add("BT");
                 });
             }

             // close command
             if (test == "Close")                 
                 pipeServer.Disconnect();               
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
     finally
     {
         //If i remove this line, The code Work
         //pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
         //if (pipeServer.IsConnected) { pipeServer.Disconnect(); }
     }
 } while (true);
```

Note that this is not a really good design, but may do for your test purposes. You probably should encapsulate the handling of a connected client into an own method or even class.

And note that `catch(Exception ex) { throw ex; }` is somewhat useless (unless you *want* to get rid of the original stacktrace).

Comment: i have try your example Renè, But the client are freezed.